# Interpolate a component into a string

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Is there any way in react to interpolate a component into an object string?

For example, I've tried something like this.

```
const stringWithHOC = `Some string wording ${<Foobar>Lorem Ipsum</Foobar>} some more string wording`
```

Assuming `<Foobar>` is a styled-components `<a>` for example

```
const Foobar = styled.a`
//some styling
`
```

I would expect to see the string rendered with "Lorem Ipsum" wrapped in an `<a>`

What is actually rendered in some component like this:

```
<SomeComponent>{stringWithHOC}</SomeComponent>
```

Is this:
"Some string wording {object Object} some more string wording"

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd expect that--think about what a component is and how it renders (via a `render` function). String interpolation doesn't run through the React component lifecycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`renderToStaticMarkup`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostaticmarkup) from `react-dom/server`

```js
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';

const reactToString = (reactElement) => ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(reactElement);
const Foobar = styled.a`
//some styling
`

const stringWithHOC = `Some string wording ${reactToString(<Foobar>Lorem Ipsum</Foobar>)} some more string wording`

// now you can use
<SomeComponent>{stringWithHOC}</SomeComponent>
```